# How to add new co-routine to already running loop in Python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I wrote a code like this.

```py
import asyncio
import time
import random

async def secondCoro(myId):
    waiting_time = random.randint(1,5)
    while 1:
        print("i am {} ".format(myId))
        time.sleep(waiting_time)


async def main():
    for i in range (10):
        await loop.create_task(secondCoro(i))
        time.sleep(0.1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I need to run 10 coroutines at the same time. I gave random sleep time so I think it will be show output like this.

```py
i am 0

i am 2

i am 4

i am 1

i am 2

i am 8

i am 5
```

But when I run this code it only shows,

```py
i am 0

i am 0

i am 0
```

Is this achievable? If yes what is problem in my code and how do I fix this? If there are no errors, are there any possible ways to run many co-routines?

Comment: Do not use ``time.sleep`` in async code. ``secondCoro`` never suspends, it just blocks the *entire* event loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- async code must not block, so instead of calling `time.sleep()`, you must await `asyncio.sleep()`.
- "await" means "wait until done", so when you await the tasks in your loop in main(), you never get past the first iteration of the loop because the task never finishes.

There are several ways to fix the second issue. For example, you can call `asyncio.gather()`, or you can keep the loop as-is, but omit the awaiting of the tasks, and instead await them in a second loop. For example:

```
async def secondCoro(myId):
    waiting_time = random.randint(1,5)
    while True:
        print("i am {} ".format(myId))
        await asyncio.sleep(waiting_time)

async def main():
    # start all the tasks
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(secondCoro(i)) for i in range(10)]
    # and await them, which will basically wait forever, while still
    # allowing all the tasks to run
    for t in tasks:
        await t

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: i change asyncio.sleep to 0.1 sec. then i add code to secondCoro before whe while start ```print("i am  {} ".format(myId)) ``` then i run this code i can see taks are run like this
it print i am 1 i am 2 i am 3 and wait one sec and again print i am 4 i am 5 i am 6 i am 7 and again wait some one or two sec. my question is why happen this?

Comment: @wisnshaftler I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the modification, nor what confuses you about the resulting behavior. But that sounds like a different question. I suggest that you play some more with the code to familiarize yourself with how the tasks work. This code is, I think, a good start.